# Assistance creating a regex

Tags: regex

Can someone help me here? I need to create a regex that will meet the following criteria:

Valid characters: 0-9 and hyphen (-) only. Entry must be between 11 and 13 characters.
Also, must not contain the string "73480"

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use regex pattern `^(?!.*73480)[0-9-]{11,13}$`

Answer (score 0):

You want two regexes for clarity.

First check that this matches:

```
/^[-\d]{11,13}$/
```

and then check for failing to match:

```
/73480/
```

In Perl you'd do this like `/^[-\d]{11,13}$/ && !/73480/`.  If this was PHP, you'd make two calls to `preg_match`.

Trying to cram it all into one regex makes things too hard to read in the future.

Comment: Disagree, in Perl I'd cram it into one regex as Omega (this is what lookaheads are for) did but follow perl monks style guidlines and split it over several lines with comments using the //x notation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I probably should have mentioned that I needed it to be one test only. I am using it in a formassembly.com form.

Answer (score -1):

There's a great regex editor online which you could try: http://txt2re.com/.

Simply enter an example of what you'd like to match and then you can click to select patterns you would like to match on.

Comment: I don't think it would work very well for the "Must not contain" part of the requirement.

Comment: Wow - that was a confusing screen. lol  Thank you for replying though.