# Regex matching phone numbers

Tags: regex

Can someone help me out here? I need a regex that will match the following pattern:

10-(any 5 digits except 73480)-(any 4 digits)

Examples
valid: 10-12345-1234
invalid: 10-73480-1234

Thanks

Comment: What was wrong with the accepted answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12628885/78845)?

Comment: where is the language tag!

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: This is a solved problem. People have already written, tested and debugged code that handles this already. Whenever you have a programming problem that others have probably had to deal with, then look for existing code that does it for you.

Comment: Johnsyweb - It was not allowing codes that should have worked. I decided to ask for help rewriting it to be more precise to the actual problem. I think I didn't spec it correctly the first time.

Comment: Andy - I doubt that someone has already solved that exact problem, but if they have it would be a coincidence, because we are dealing with an internal code, not a phone number.

Comment: And finally, I'd like to comment on the "closed as too localized". I thought that this community existed as a resource to get help with programming problems. Why should I have to generalize my question just to get help? If there is a better place to ask such questions, then please forgive my ignorance and feel free to point me there. I'm going to read the FAQ now.

Comment: This is from the FAQ:
Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

The very first one says "a specific programming problem", which is what I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use negative lookahead to check for any occurance of `10-73480` before matching..

```
^(?!10-73480)10-\d{5}-\d{4}$
```

Try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)